# Can I pass the result of an assignment to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, variable-assignment

My question is: "Can I pass the result of an assignment to a function in c++?"

The reason I want to do this is that a variable has a specific type, e.g. "int" so I assign the value to the variable and pass the whole thing to the overloaded function that takes "int" as an argument.

The main reason for doing this is to make the code a bit smaller and easier to read, so instead of:

```
val = 2
function(val);
```

I get:

```
function(val = 2);
```

Is that ok?
If so, is there a convention that says this is poor coding practice for some reason?

Thanks,
fodder

Comment: “smaller” I can see. “easier to read” I don’t get. Don’t try to be clever, be simple. Assign first, then call the function. This definitely not idiomatic C++ code, nor is it recommended.

Comment: If I saw `function(val = 2);` my first impression might be that you'd written `function(val == 2);`, i.e passing a boolean. Your first method is clearly better.

Comment: Both valid points :) ... I had not considered how it would look to the next user :o

Comment: `function(val = 2);` looks like named arguments to me :) which C++ doesn't support (yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

Per paragraph `§ 5.17 / 1`

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

After `function(val = 2)`,  `2` assigns to `val` then the value of `val` passes to the function.

Talking about readability is not easy, I personally don't use this way in my codes.

Comment: thanks for the answer :), I did not understand the last part about the chain of assignments....

Comment: The expression `a = b = c` is evaluated as `a = (b = c)`. `b = c` will assign `c` to `b` and then yield `b` as result. This is then assigned to `a`, yielding `a` as result. You can pass any expression (hope I'm not leaning too far out of the window with the exact meaning of the term) to a function, including one that contains an assignment. Note that using overloaded operators on user-defined types, you can break the rule that an assignment yields the left side as result.

Comment: @doomster: _almost_ every expression. The term is correct, the syntax allows it, but semantically you're forbidden from passing expressions with `void` type. E.g. Given function `void f();`, the expression `f()` cannot be passed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "Can I pass the result of an assignment to a function in c++?"
```

Yes off course we can do this . compiler will break this statement `function(val = 2)` in 
two steps that is first assign 2 to `val` then make a call to function with parameter 2 . therefore the first two liner  approach is much  cleaner and readable from the second.

Comment: Actually, the call will be made with `val`, not `2`. This matters when calling `void function(int& param)` - you can't modify 2, but you can modify `val`.

Comment: function will be called with val which is 2 it is not a call by reference its call by value .

Comment: Why do you assume it's a call by value? Besides, there are other cases where the difference can be noted. E.g. when `function` takes another type, and a conversion is needed, then `val` will be converted.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does indeed allow this but I wouldn't do it if I were you.

Not everything that c++ allows you to do is a good idea. A good programmer must consider two things: readability and maintainabilty. A blogger (I can't remember who) once said that a programmer doesn't program for computers, they should program for programmers.

What this means is that you should try and make things as easy to read as possible. Condensing multiple lines into one actually decreases readabilty because the reader has to stop and think about more than one thing, they have to analyse the condensed statement instead of just reading it.

What you want to do can also hide bugs created by typos. Say, for instance, you typed

```
function(val == 2)
```

by mistake. The compiler would allow this as well since it will convert a bool into an int. Another reader also won't pick up this mistake unless he/she knows the parameter list well.

If you're interested in tips and tricks and advice on good programming construction techniques, I would highly recommend [Code Complete 2](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cc.htm). I have had the book for years and I still learn new things to improve my code.

Comment: Thanks for that RobbieE. Nice bit of extra info for me there :)  ... I will take a look at this book as well.